# Discord.js | Custom Guild Emoji on React Collection not working

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So i'm trying to use custom guild emoji to my react collection however it does react but doesnt response when i try to react.

I ask many people for a straight and all they did is to give me some advise and random answer that will lead to "guessing" like im already "guessing the error" and they giving me another thing to guest. not just point out the line code I was wrong or the wrong implementation i did.

```js
                const nojob = new Discord.MessageEmbed() 
                .setTitle(` | Prunity Jobs | ${message.author.username}`)   
                .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL())   
                .setDescription(`You currently don't have prunity job. \n Would you like to apply for a virtual job?`)      
                .addFields(
                    { name: 'Available Job', value: "<:mintme:887802825667657779> - MintMe  **|**  <:xmr:887802683094880266> - Monero"} 
                    )                         
                .setColor('#b491c8')                  
                .setFooter('Click  to cancel this operation.');
                var nojobMsg = await message.channel.send(nojob); 
                    await nojobMsg.react(`:mintme:887802825667657779`);
                    await nojobMsg.react(`:xmr:887802683094880266`);
                    await nojobMsg.react(`:cancel:887819337744932874`);
                    const filter = (reaction, user) => [`887802825667657779`, `887802683094880266`,`887819337744932874`].includes(reaction.emoji.id) && user.id === message.author.id;
                    const collector = nojobMsg.createReactionCollector(filter, {
                        time: 120000
                    });
                    collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
                        reaction.emoji.reaction.users.remove(user.id);
                        switch (reaction.emoji.id) {  

                            //MintMe 
                            case `887802825667657779`:
                                const fish = new Discord.MessageEmbed()                 
                                .setTitle(` | Prunity Jobs | ${message.author.username}`)   
                                .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL())    
                                .setColor('#b491c8')      
                                .addFields(
                                { name: 'MintMe', value: "Please wait, I'm applying you to your virtual job.."} 
                                )                                         
                                .setFooter(`Command requested by: ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`)                                   
                                nojobMsg.reactions.removeAll();
                                nojobMsg.edit(fish);
                                connection.query(`UPDATE users SET job='MINTME' WHERE user_id=${message.author.id}`, async function (error, results, fields) {
                                    if (error) throw error;
                                    else{
                                        const success = new Discord.MessageEmbed()                 
                                        .setTitle(' | Prunity Jobs')       
                                        .setColor('#b491c8')      
                                        .addFields(
                                        { name: 'Congrats!', value: "<:mintme:887802825667657779> | You are now working for MINTME!"} 
                                        )                                         
                                        .setFooter(`Command requested by: ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`)    
                                        nojobMsg.reactions.removeAll();                               
                                        nojobMsg.edit(success);  
                                        connection.end();                                                                              
                                    }
                                });
                                break;   

                            //XMR
                            case '887802683094880266':
                                const farm = new Discord.MessageEmbed()                 
                                .setTitle(` | Prunity Jobs | ${message.author.username}`)   
                                .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL())    
                                .setColor('#b491c8')      
                                .addFields(
                                { name: 'Monero', value: "Please wait, I'm applying you to your virtual job.."} 
                                )                                         
                                .setFooter(`Command requested by: ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`)                                   
                                nojobMsg.reactions.removeAll();
                                nojobMsg.edit(farm);
                                //Create user job on database
                                connection.query(`UPDATE users SET job='XMR' WHERE user_id=${message.author.id}`, async function (error, results, fields) {
                                    if (error) throw error;
                                    else{
                                        const success = new Discord.MessageEmbed()                 
                                        .setTitle(' | Prunity Jobs')       
                                        .setColor('#b491c8')      
                                        .addFields(
                                        { name: 'Congrats!', value: "<:xmr:887802683094880266> | You are now working for XMR!"} 
                                        )                                         
                                        .setFooter(`Command requested by: ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`)    
                                        nojobMsg.reactions.removeAll();                               
                                        nojobMsg.edit(success);  
                                        connection.end();                                                                              
                                    }
                                });
                                break;                                                          

                                //Cancel
                                case `887819337744932874`:
                                    const no = new Discord.MessageEmbed()                 
                                    .setTitle(` | Prunity Jobs | ${message.author.username}`)   
                                    .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL())      
                                    .setColor('#b491c8')      
                                    .addFields(
                                    { name: 'Operation Cancelled', value: "No virtual job has been applied."} 
                                    )                                         
                                    .setFooter(`Command requested by: ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`)   
                                    
                                    nojobMsg.reactions.removeAll();
                                    nojobMsg.edit(no);
                                    break;                                                                 
                        };
                    });
                    collector.on('end', collected => {             
                        const done = new Discord.MessageEmbed()                 
                        .setTitle(` | Prunity Jobs | ${message.author.username}`)   
                        .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL())          
                        .setColor('#b491c8')     
                        .addFields(
                            { name: 'Reaction Timeout', value: "I'm done looking for reactions on the message!"} 
                        )                                         
                        .setFooter(`Command requested by: ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`)                             
                        nojobMsg.reactions.removeAll();
                        nojobMsg.edit(done);
                        });
            }
```

Comment: This is v12 by the way, hope someone can help me with this. this is my first time implementing the emoji since i always use normal emojis before which can be copy and paste on the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give you some advice: look at your console for errors, and if there are console errors then mention them in the question. In this situation, we were the ones who needed to "guess the error" because you did not mention the console error that makes it easy to solve your problem.

Because you did not mention the error, I copied and pasted your code into my own bot (replacing your emotes with my own) and tested it myself to find out what was wrong. I found the issue immediately after testing it just once. This is the error it gave me when I clicked on one of the reactions:

```
reaction.emoji.reaction.users.remove(user.id);
                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined
```

That solves your problem pretty easily. No need for guessing errors, because your console is quite literally telling you what the error is.

You're doing `reaction.emoji.reaction.users`, but `reaction.emoji.reaction` doesn't exist. It doesn't make sense either; if you already have the `reaction`, why would you get the emoji from the reaction just to get the reaction again? What you're looking for instead of that line is:

```js
reaction.users.remove(user.id);
```

There's your direct answer.

> I ask many people for a straight and all they did is to give me some advise and random answer that will lead to "guessing" like im already "guessing the error" and they giving me another thing to guest. not just point out the line code I was wrong or the wrong implementation i did.

I'm guessing the reason people were saying that is because this problem should be *very* easy to solve using proper/normal debugging or even just basic testing. As I mentioned above, I found the issue instantly. The console told me what the error was in seconds. Yours should have as well. Users on StackOverflow and elsewhere want you to properly learn how to find and fix errors on your own, so that you don't have to ask a question here every single time some small error pops up in your code; in the long run, it'll help you grow so much more as a developer.